# Prototype Equivalent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

What will be the equivalent of below prototype in jQuery?

```
rowTag = 'li' , style = ('display', 'none') and

html = <div class="nobr">..... </div>

element = new Element(rowTag, style).insert(html);
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: reason for down vote ?

Comment: `Element` represents an interface that is not directly instantiated by itself.  Instead things inherit from it to make a specific type of tag.  So, what type of tag are you trying  to create?  Are you trying to create a `<tr>` tag?  Is that what "rowTag" means?  I didn't downvote, but your downvotes are probably because your question is not very clear and your question shows no signs of your own research or attempts to solve the problem on  your own.

Comment: @ArvindRajput We expect people to show that they've done some basic research before asking a question.

Comment: Are you just making up code?   Your code `element = new Element(rowTag, style).insert(html);` is not something you can do in browser Javascript.  As such, you should use words, not illegal code to describe what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create element and assign attributes like this:

```
$('<tag/>', {
    id:   'foo',
    text: 'Go to Google!'
});
```

and then you can use one of [DOM Insertion methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)